# Ubuntu cannot log in

Tags: system

My Ubuntu only allowed guest login to desktop.Once I login to System as user ,It jump to login interface again and very quick 
please i need a simple answer with a simple langauge

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try this. Open a TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. Login here and run `sudo apt-get install gdm`. Choose it as default when prompted and reboot.

Comment: lol i dont know what's tty

Comment: You don't need to. Just press those keys.

Comment: and how to choose it as default .... ?

Comment: It will prompt you. Read the answer fully through.

Comment: ok bro i'll try it i really preshaydit

Comment: i'm not lucky 
i did the steps

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: it is saying that login incorrect 
i'm typing the correct pass word

Comment: You can just type the password. You need to type your username, hit enter and then type tour password.

Comment: when it appears the black screen i writte sudo apt-get install gdm

Comment: do you have a facebook account ?

Comment: You can't just type it right away. When the screen comes up, wait a few seconds and it will prompt you for your username. After entering that and hitting enter, you will be asked for your password. Once you login, run the command.

Comment: i did it but it said that gdm is already installed 
but the good new is that i logged in 
i just type sudo startx and then it works

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Version number and name; ex: Kubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

Installing GDM is one possible solution, but it's probably not the one you're looking for. Again, press [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [F1] and log on. This time, however, type

```
sudo chown -R username /home/username
```

replace usename with your username in the cases above. So if you are user john, type

```
sudo chown -R john /home/john
```

and this will make your user the owner of everything in your home folder. This is where all of the settings your computer uses are stored. Because the guest account works, I think this is probably your problem.

If that doesn't work, try again logging in to TTY1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) then type

```
cd
```

Then type

```
rm -Rf ./.*
```

**WARNING!!: THIS WILL ERASE YOUR EMAIL, FIREFOX, DESKTOP BACKGROUND, etc. SETTINGS!**

While this means that you will have to re-set the background and retype your passwords in thunderbird and other network apps, it should allow you to log in. Please also note this will delete any GPG keys you may have created. If you don't know what that is, don't worry about it, it's not important in that case.

Good luck with this, usually the problem is something stupidly simple but devilishly hard to find.